# Magento Order Grid in back-end is not showing

Tags: magento, grid, orders

I have a problem with my magento shop.

Its version 1.5.1 I'm using.

Have have made the shop on a local host and all working fine.
When I put on my live web then the sales orders are not showing up in the magento back-end. All works fine on localhost.

Have tried a lot of different things but nothing works.

On the magento back-end dashboard I can see the last 5 orders and have no problem to enter the order from there. The problem is if I get more than 5 orders, then it will not be possible for me to enter the current order.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any extension on live website?

If yes, try after disabling that extension.

If no, then go to **System >> Configuration** and Click on **Developer** tab.

Now Enable Log from **Log Settings**.

Now refresh order grid page and check whether there is any new log under ***var/log*** folder.

If still problem could not be traced, then open ***index.php*** and change:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will enable developer mode and whne you will refresh the page next time, it will show the error on page.

I hope, this process can help you in rectifying your problem.